# Arduino connected via TCP using SIM900 to Dweet.io

Tags: arduino, sensors, gsm, sim900, dweet.io

I am trying to stream some sensor data to Dweet.io using my Arduino connected to a SIM900 GSM/GPRS module. I am able to access internet, load data, check GPRS connectivity etc from my Arduino board. Could someone specifically tell me the syntax to post data onto dweet.io?

Comment: ARDuino, not ADRuino

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Using the AT commands use this library its easier and Nice https://github.com/amcewen/HttpClient

Dweet.io needs GET commands to send and receive data.